# What is the right way to cite a source?

Tags: punctuation, style

I have included some data in the text. I would like to add a line to give information about the source of the data.

My question is, what is the right way to do it? The following are some possible ways to do it.

1. Source: World Bank “Annual Report 2019”
2. Source: World Bank, “Annual Report 2019”
3. Source: “Annual Report 2019”, World Bank
4. Source: World Bank *Annual Report 2019*
5. Source: World Bank, *Annual Report 2019*
6. Source: *Annual Report 2019*, World Bank

Thank you.

Comment: If you google **best way to cite a source**, you will find numerous helpful websites.

Comment: There's no single correct way to cite sources.  It depends on the norms of the publication you're writing for, or the style guide you're following.  You could do a lot worse than number 5 above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no “correct” way to do citations; it is a matter of *style*.

Formal writing, especially in an academic or professional setting, should have a style guide provided that, among many other things, tells you what is required for citations. If you don’t have a style guide to follow, you can just pick one; I suggest looking at those published by major newspapers in the UK (BrE) or US (for AmE), which are comprehensive and widely adopted.

Informal writing can follow whatever your personal style is. As long as you are consistent and readers can understand you, that’s good enough.